# General form of rank $2$ tensor invaiant under certain rotations

Tags: tensors, rotations

I have the problem of determining the most general form of a rank 2 tensor $t_{ij}$ (in 3 dimensions) satisfying:

- $t_{ij}$ is invariant under any rotation about the $z$-axis
- $t_{ij}$ is invariant under a rotation by $\pi$ about any axis in the $(x,y)$-plane through the origin

The question asks me to show the most general form of the above tensor is

$$t_{ij} = \alpha \delta_{ij} + \beta \delta_{i3}\delta_{j3}$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding about how to solve problems like this, since, taking the first bullet point, we would want

$$t_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta &- \sin \theta & 0\\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}t_{ij} \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$$

So in particular, taking $\theta = \pi$ we would want

$$t_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}t_{ij} \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$$

which would make the entries of $t$ for $i=1,2$ to be $0$, and thus requiring $\alpha = 0$ in the given most general form, so this shouldn't be right.

I'm also struggling to see how I could check that the second condition is obeyed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The transformation rule of rank 2 tensor should be t_{ik}A_{kl}t_{lj} …

Comment: Almost Benjamin, the transformation needs the transpose (=inverse since orthogonal transformation) $\bar{t}_{mk}=r_{im}t_{ij}r_{jk}$, Compare $\bar{A}=R^{-1}AR$ in matrix notation.